# text input field alignment

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm having a problem trying to align text inputs. Here's what my page looks like initially:

[image: Initial page]
After adding the following css code:

```
#items{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 500px;
    clear: both;        
}
```

I now get this:
[image: After css code is added]

Notice that the inputs under "Poids Total(kg)" disappear.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have position relative and absolute mixed probably. Or working with floats. Both floats and position absolute do not follow the normal document flow. Specifying position relative may give unexpected results. Can you post your HTML in a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you css is moving that away with 500px. change it to 5px and see or adjust accordingly

```
#items{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 5px;
    clear: both;        
}
```

Comment: That was it, now i feel stupid. Thanks for pointing that out, the probleme that is , not my stupidity  lol :p